# Does a pet bring bring back explorer's items that were found?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I'm playing fallout shelter, I accidentally left a dweller exploring the wasteland for to long, and he died. He had a pet, and when my dweller died his pet started coming back to the vault. I was just wondering, (because it's taking ages for the pet to come back), does the pet bring back what the dweller found before he died?

Answer (score 5):

**Yes.** The pet will bring back anything equipped to the owner, as well as any items collected in the wasteland. For this reason, I often assign a pet to each dweller going into the wasteland as a gear recovery insurance policy, even if the pet provides no benefit in the wasteland (x2 healing, -crafting cost, etc.).

Comment: +1, this is true. Getting back the equipped items is often so important in survival that I do the same thing. A good gun matters more than a dweller.